# Use multi-threading save UserControls as image the error is :The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it

Tags: c#, wpf

I want use Mutli-Thread save all `UserControl` as image at the same time want to show animation view on the screen, but have an error:

> The calling thread cannot access this object because a different
>   thread owns it.

This is my code:

```
private void OnScreenShotAllCommandExecuted(object parameter)
{
    string filePath = @"D:\ScreenShot\";
    IList<UserControl> userControls = LayoutRoot.Children.OfType<UserControl>().ToList();
    List<Thread> tasks = new List<Thread>();
    AnimationView animationView = new AnimationView();
    animationView.Show();

    foreach (UserControl userControl in userControls)
    {
        string viewName = userControl.Name;
        string fileName = userControl.Name + ".png";
        if (viewName != null)
        {
            Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                SaveView(userControl, fileName, filePath);
                 ThreadHasFinished();
            });
            tasks.Add(thread);
            thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            thread.Start();
        }
    }
}

private void ThreadHasFinished()
{
    Interlocked.Increment(ref finishedControls);

    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
    {
        animationView.Close();

    }));

}

public static void SaveView(UserControl userControl, string fileName, string destFolder)
{
    Rect bounds = VisualTreeHelper.GetDescendantBounds(userControl);

    int width = (int)view.RenderSize.Width;
    int height = (int)view.RenderSize.Height;

    RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap(width, height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);

    DrawingVisual dv = new DrawingVisual();
    using (DrawingContext ctx = dv.RenderOpen())
    {
        VisualBrush vb = new VisualBrush(userControl);
        ctx.DrawRectangle(vb, new Pen(Brushes.Blue, 2), new Rect(new Point(0, 100), size));
    }
    rtb.Render(dv);
    PngBitmapEncoder png = new PngBitmapEncoder();
    png.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(rtb));

    using (Stream fileStream = new FileStream(string.Format("{0}\\{1}.png", destFolder, fileName), FileMode.Create))
    {
        png.Save(fileStream);
    }        
}
```

The error

> The calling thread cannot access this object because a different
>   thread owns it.

is on this line

`Rect bounds = VisualTreeHelper.GetDescendantBounds(userControl);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(1000);
                        SaveView(userControl, fileName, filePath);
                         ThreadHasFinished();
                    });
```

In the above code you are calling  `SaveView(userControl, fileName, filePath)` which is wrong as WPF update UI on the main thread.

For Responsive UI, instead of creating threads directly I suggest you to use [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) in this case. You will have `RunWorkerCompleted` event which will be on the main thread, so you can update any UIElement in that. And expensive stuff you can run under `DoWork` event. DoWork run on the background thread from the Thread Pool.

Comment: Hi, Mukesh Rawat 

I tried to use BackgroundWorker, but I don't know how to use BackgroundWorker because of I am new in WPF multi-threading. Can you help me make a demo about my problem?
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A general design principle of many UI frameworks, including WPF and Windows Forms, is that of thread affinity. Specifically, the thread that *creates* a UI element is the *only* thread that can *interact* with it.

If you are trying to directly interact with your UI elements with multiple different threads, your design is fundamentally flawed.

Note that anything which does not directly interact with a usercontrol *may* run on a different thread. Disk I/O, etc, e.g.

To marshal between your worker thread and UI thread (99% of basic applications have exactly, only one UI thread), use the element's dispatcher from the worker thread. The Dispatcher will allow you to queue a request to the ui thread and get its result. Read up on MSDN for more detail.